# R: Replacing x-axis labels with row names in a plot

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I'm trying to draw a plot using the below matrix. I need the row names in the x-axis and draw a plot for each of the columns in the matrix.

```
            M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7 M8 M9 M10
EPS_0     1727  4  3  3  2  2  2  2  2   2
EPS_0.1   1525  6  5  3  3  3  2  2  2   2
EPS_0.2   1487  9  5  4  3  3  3  2  2   2
EPS_0.3   1423 12  4  4  3  3  3  3  2   2
EPS_0.4   1406 12  6  5  3  3  3  3  2   2
EPS_0.5   1383 11  7  6  4  3  3  3  2   2
EPS_0.6   1365 12  7  5  5  5  4  4  2   2
EPS_0.7   1357 13  6  6  5  4  3  3  2   3
EPS_0.8   1326 18 10  7  7  6  5  4  3   3
EPS_0.9   1304 15 11  9  8  7  6  5  4   3
EPS_1     1290 16 12 10 10  9  8  5  4   3
```

Below is my code and the graph I created.

```
layout(rbind(1,2), heights=c(7,1))

matplot(clData, type="l", ylim=c(0,10),  lwd=1, col=1:10, lty=1,
        xlab = "EPS Value", ylab = "No of Clusters", 
        main = "No of Clusters for EPS-MinPtc combination")
axis(1, at=0:10, labels=rownames(clData),las=2)
```

[image]

I couldn't directly get the row names of the matrix to the plot. I guess it's because the data is stored in a matrix object. I was referring to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036830/how-to-plot-columns-of-a-matrix-on-a-single-line-graph-in-r). Therefore I wanted to replace the x-axis labels with the row names of the matrix. I was able to achieve this. But the original x- axis values are still visible.

**I want to know how can I remove the original x-axis values and reduce the font size of the labels and move the xlab below the column names.**

Comment: try `matplot(..., xaxt = 'n')` and add the data to your question not as an image

Comment: Thank you for your answer however this resulted in an error. I checked the matplot function definition and I didn't find this in the documentation. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/matplot.html

Comment: it is passed to `?par`